# How to fix 'Nonetype' error when approaching a functional way to solve two sum problem in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve the leetcode problem "Two Sum" in a functional manner but I face an error on line 11 and 12 saying 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

```py
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        def allSum(solnSet, nums, target):
            if nums == []:
                return list(map(list, set(map(lambda x: tuple(x), solnSet))))
            elif (int(sum(solnSet)) + int(nums[0])) <= target:
                return allSum(solnSet.append(nums[0]), nums[1:], target)
            else:
                return allSum(solnSet, nums[1:], target)

        soln =[]
        v = allSum(soln, nums, target)
        return v

o = Solution()
print(o.twoSum([1,2,3,4,5], 5))
```

[1,4]

Comment: this problem seems a lot more easy to solve with the use of two nested loop. It is not clear at all what you want to achive with recursion, maybe you should add more details.

Comment: OP is looking for a "functional" way of solving it. Recursion can be a good challenge sometimes. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the trouble maker:

```
solnSet.append(nums[0])
```

Appending to a `list` doesn't return anything (so by default, it returns `None`). When your function performs recursion on `allSum(solnSet.append(nums[0]), nums[1:], target)`, **you're actually passing `None` into the first argument**.

This will raise a `'NoneType' object is not iterable` exception when your code runs `map(lambda x: tuple(x), solnSet)` or `sum(solnSet)`.

To resolve this, you could do

```
allSum(solnSet + [nums[0]], nums[1:], target)
```

(this creates a new list and doesn't modify the original)

or

```
solnSet.append(nums[0])
allSum(solnSet, nums[1:], target)
```

(but this *does* modify the original).